# Complex field is grayed out

Tags: entity-framework

I am following the [example](http://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/archive/2010/08/18/entity-framework-4-0-bind-stored-procedure-with-result-entity-class.aspx) to pratice binding stored procedure in Entity Framework.

However the complex field is grayed out, I am unable to go further.

Please see the image.

[image]

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET3.5 only support EF3.5, but this version doesn't support complex type, so the button is disabled. .NET4.0 or later will be fine.